# Visual Studio NuGet says I have 3 vulnerable packages, then shows me 0

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

So NuGet says I have 3 vulnerable packages. But when I then ask for a listing of the vulnerable packages, I get 0. What is going on here?

**Update**: And it gets weirder. I updated Visual Studio and now:

1. Looking at NuGet for the solution it says I have 1 vulnerable package, but shows 0.
2. Looking at NuGet for my main web project it says I have 5 vulnerable packages - and shows all 5.

So clearly there's some bugs around this in the latest Visual Studio pre-release.

[image]

Comment: Noticed you're using a pre-release of Visual Studio...does this happen in other versions?

Comment: @Alex No idea - I only have the pre-release version. But I just checked - there's an update. I'll update and then post if that makes any difference. Tthanks

Comment: I done a test on vs commnity 17.9.0 preview 4.0, and this seems no problem, how do you create the local azure function. based on azure function sdk 4.0?

Comment: You could take a look of my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ways to check risk:

```
dotnet list package --vulnerable
```

If there is really some risk packages there, then you will get:

[image]

NuGet obtains its information regarding Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE) and GitHub Security Advisories (GHSA) directly from the centralized GitHub Advisory Database. This database provides listings of known vulnerabilities, where a CVE is a list of publicly disclosed computer security flaws, and a GHSA is a GitHub Security Advisory. Nuget package management risk report based on this.

So if you couldn't find the risk packages via the command, then it s believed that the situation you encountered is caused by temporary issue of Visual Studio preview version.

Comment: I just updated my questions with further results. And yes, it looks like the answer is bugs in Visual Studio.

Comment: remember to also use `--include-transitive`, as the vulnerable packages might not be packages referenced directly.

Comment: Is this command only valid for one sln file? or for example if I have more than one sln, will it scan all of them?

Sorry for jumping :)